# How do a run tests without the @Tag annotation

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I have a class that has tag annotation at the very top and then I have tests that have annotation (these tests are to be ignored) and then tests that don't have annotation.

The ones withOUT annotation need to be run.

**I have tried** Tag expressions with the surefire plugin

```java
@Tag("integration")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(JupiterTimingExtension.class)
@DisplayName("Test this for integration selectively")
public class exampleTests {

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class validAccount{

    @Tag("doNotRunThese")
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Not a integration test")
    void testImages() {}

    @Tag("pleaseRunThis")
    @Test
    @DisplayName("this is a integration test")
    void testText(){}
}
```

**pom.xml** surefire plugin area

```xml
<properties>
<excludedGroups>doNotRunThese</excludedGroups>
<groups>integration &amp; !(doNotRunThese | regression)</groups>
</properties>
```

I want to run the `testText` method and not the `testImages` method. But when I run using MVN test the `testText` method does not run.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a typo of extra space and once that was removed, the mvn test started working, also to exclude tests from command line you can use mvn test -DexcludeGroups=xyz or to include use mvn test -Dgroups=abc